# Understand SLU_SC format matrix and convert to normal CSR

Tags: sparse-matrix, solver

The SLU_SC in SuperLU is defined as "Supernode, column-wise". It's generally the result of running SuperLU on a sparse matrix.

I would like to inspect this matrix instead of solving for a vector so the CSR / COO format would be nice. Any pointer on how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using a high level language interface to `SuperLU` you can use Python together with `scipy`. You can call the [`spilu`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu) method and then access and convert the  `L` and `U` of the resulting [`SuperLU`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.SuperLU.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.SuperLU) object to all the standard sparse matrix formats.